# winpwn for windows 7 problem help need

Tags: windows-7, iphone

I've been trying to install winpwn 2.5 in windows 7 but it's not compatible. Winpwn is just compatible for winxp and below; and I don't have any computer or laptop that has a different Operating System. Any solution to solve my problem? The reason for that is I want to fix my Iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install [Windows Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) you can install XP on the virtual PC and then install winpwn on that.

However, from the page:

> Windows Virtual PC requires a CPU with the Intel® Virtualization Technology or AMD-V™ feature turned on. This feature must be enabled in the system BIOS.

And you may also need an XP license key, though there is an "XP Mode" download on that page as well.